ElasticSearch: Need to aggregate on an aggregation to get count of status values based on last field for each session
We have a series of status updates for projects and the last update for a given project is the one we want to report on in several ways. For instance:



ProjectID
DateTime
EventDescription




001
2024-12-07 11:34
New


001
2024-12-07 11:36
Submitted


002
2024-12-07 11:40
New


003
2024-12-07 12:34
New


001
2024-12-07 14:02
Approved


002
2024-12-07 14:55
Submitted


004
2024-12-07 15:02
New


004
2024-12-07 15:44
Submitted


001
2024-12-07 16:03
Completed



In our actual data, there are, of course, thousands of projects and many more status updates.
THE GOAL:
We have to use an aggregation to grab the last status (the current status) for each project, but we want a summary of the project status and count of each in a datetime range.
For the data above, we want to get:



Status
Project Count




New
1


Submitted
2


Completed
1



We are looking for a means to do this in a single query. We have several places where we need this. This is just one example, and using a transformation is not a viable option at this time.
In addition to simple counts, we next hope to figure out how to aggregate these status updates into bucket counts by day to show a status graph across a series of days. How many each day are New, Submitted, etc... But we would be thrilled just to get status counts accurately.
We believe this requires a pipeline aggregation, but have not been able to get it working.
Our working aggregation query to get the latest project status for project:
GET journaling*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "range": {
          "DATETIME": {
            "gte":"2024/11/01 00:00:00.000",
            "lte":"2024/11/30 23:59:59.000"
          }
        }},
        {
          "match": {
            "ACCOUNT": "12345"
          }
        }
      ]      
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ProjectStatusSummary": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "PROJECTID"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": "1",
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "DATETIME",
                "PROJECTID",
                "EVENTDESCRIPTION",
                "PROJECTSTART"
              ]
            },
            "sort": {
              "DATETIME": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I have learned a bit more. I explored 2 options.
I tried to aggregate on this aggregation and received an error from Elastic because it does not like sub-aggregations on a top_hits.
I also tried collapsing as a different means to get the latest status, which works great, but I do not yet see a way to aggregate on the output of a collapse either.

Continuing to learn. I have tried a "max" aggregation for the DATETIME field, and it does return the correct records, but I have not yet been able to get the fields for the selected record, just the document key and the actual datetime value. This max aggregation could work if I could figure out how to get the other fields for the max document.

And I learned max aggregations, just like top_hits, cannot accept sub-aggregations.

I would think wanting to work on a set of most recent records for each order, customer or whatever would be very useful, but so far not possible. If you collapse to get most recent, then I do not see a way to aggregate on the collapse results. If you use a top_hits aggregation, then you cannot sub-aggregate on the results. If you use a max aggregation, then you cannot sub-aggregate on the results or see the other fields in the max record found.

I believe using named pipelines is my best and final option to achieve what I need, but I have not figured out a named pipeline aggregation yet that fetches records. All the examples I have seen are about doing math and ending up with a numeric result.
